# Docusign API - Authorization Code Grant- Secretkey

Tags: docusignapi

For the Authorization Code Grant, is the Secret Key supposed to be mapped to 
each individual user?

When an email is sent out, what would be the sender's email?

thanks,

J

Additional info for Larry:

This is awesome!. Stockflow is really actively monitored by Docusign!                     I'm using JWT.
I have a user configured. 
I assume email body will be similar to following one.

My question is if secret key is used to identify application, the customer knows the email is sent from the application, but how does he know which employee using the application send the email?

Please see following email body:                                                                             Test             --------------> User name

maaaa@example.com  ------->User's email (**This indicates the user's email address sending document via docusign**)

signer name,

Please DocuSign a.pdf

Thank You, Test

Answer (score 0):

For Authorization Code grant, the application identifies itself via its client id (Integration Key) and its Secret.

The secret is associated with the application, not with the user.

When you say "email ... sent out" what email are you referring to?